# ResultSet not open although i have only one at a time

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I know many questions were  asked before for this issue but for this situations I can't find an answer.

This is my code:

```
private Collection<Coupon> getCouponsMain(Company company, String filters) throws DAOException
{
    String sql = null;
    if (filters != null)
    {
        sql = "SELECT couponsystem.coupon.* FROM couponsystem.company_coupon LEFT JOIN couponsystem.coupon ON "
            + "couponsystem.company_coupon.COUPON_ID = couponsystem.coupon.ID WHERE couponsystem.company_coupon.COMP_ID = ? AND ?";
    }
    else
    {       
         sql = "SELECT couponsystem.coupon.* FROM couponsystem.company_coupon LEFT JOIN couponsystem.coupon ON "
            + "couponsystem.company_coupon.COUPON_ID = couponsystem.coupon.ID WHERE couponsystem.company_coupon.COMP_ID = ?";           
    }

    try (Connection con = pool.OpenConnection(); PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);)
    {   
        // query command

        preparedStatement.setLong(1, company.getId());
        if (filters != null)
        {
            preparedStatement.setString(2, filters);
        }

        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next())
        {
            CouponDBDAO couponDao = new CouponDBDAO();  
            rs.previous();
            return couponDao.BuildCoupons(rs);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException | NullPointerException e)
    {
        throw new DAOException("Failed to retrieve data for all coupons" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I think the query itself is not the important issue here but, once I use `next()` for the ResultSet, I get the error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed"

This usually happened when using two rs for same statement, this is not the case this time.

Due to many issues with previous method and BuildCoupons(rs) issue, also this part does not work properly for the same reason:

```
@Override
public Company getCompany(long id) throws DAOException
{
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM couponsystem.company WHERE ID = ?";
    try (Connection con = pool.OpenConnection(); PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);)
    {   
        // query command

        preparedStatement.setLong(1, id);

        // query execution
        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        Company comp = new Company();
        if (rs.next())
        {
            //Fill customer object from Customer table              
            comp.setId(rs.getLong("ID"));
            comp.setCompName(rs.getString("COMP_NAME"));
            comp.setPassword(rs.getString("PASSWORD"));
            comp.setEmail(rs.getString("EMAIL"));
            comp.setCoupons(comp.getCoupons());
        }   
        else
        {
            comp = null;
        }

        return comp;
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        throw new DAOException("Failed to retrieve data for customer id: " + id);
    }
}
```

BTW - working with MySQL and insert, update and delete queries are working properly so there not issue with the connection to the db

Another update - 
Once i replace it to regular statement, it's working but of course i'm losing all the advantages of prepared statement

Like i said i create new code in order to isolate the big program
This is the code:

```
public class testState 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException
    {
            DBDAO pool = DBDAO.getInstance();

            String sql = "SELECT ID FROM couponsystem.company WHERE COMP_NAME = ? AND PASSWORD = ?";
            String compName = "t";
            String password = "t";

            pool.CreatePool();
            Connection con = pool.OpenConnection(); 
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);

                preparedStatement.setString(1, compName);
                preparedStatement.setString(2, password);
preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

                System.out.println("rs status: " + rs.isClosed());
                if (rs.next())
                {
                    System.out.println("log-in was successfuly performed");
                    System.out.println(rs.getLong(1));
                    System.out.println("hjhjh");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("-1");
                }

            rs.close();
            preparedStatement.close();
            con.close();
            pool.CloseConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Which line throws the exception? 2) Why are you calling `rs.previous()`? 3) You know that `rs.previous()` returns a boolean just like `rs.next()` does, right?

Comment: This line: if (rs.next())
The reason for the previous is:  i have a function that starts with while (rs.next()) and i need to go back one row

Comment: sorry, are you getting exception at rs.next() or rs.previous()?

Comment: @TalRoth where exactly are you getting error ? which line?

Comment: @Nishank He's answered that. `rs.next()`. Stop asking questions that have already been answered.

Comment: @OP This exception is not caused by using two result sets. It is caused by using a result set after it, or its statement, or its connection have been closed. It seems to me that this is not the real code. NB you can't add entire WHERE clauses with the ? notation so this technique won't work anyway. You need to rethink.

Comment: Please post the stack trace. I have no belief in the existence of this problem as stated.

Comment: @EJP Is it possible it works fine but once i am using debugger it failed?

Comment: Until you post the stack trace it is impossible to comment. Is it a secret?

Comment: It suggests that the original poster is not in great need of our help to find a solution.

Comment: Could you post the shortest possible code demonstrating the problem ? {MCVE] would be best.  For example if you "think the query itself is not the important issue" use the simplest possible query to demonstrate the problem. BTW: In many cases preparing an MCVE pinpoints the problem and helps you solve it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It practically proves my contention that the entire problem is imaginary.

Comment: Your exception-handling here is terrible. Discarding the original exception and stacktrace means you can't know what happened.

Comment: I made some test with all the exception in the code above, this is the problem when it reaches rs.next()


Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:910)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.checkClosed(ResultSet.java:666)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.next(ResultSet.java:7274)
 at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.next(NewProxyResultSet.java:685)
 at com.CouponSystem.testState.testState.main(testState.java:34)

Comment: As expected, that exception is not thrown by this code. There is no `main()` method here.

Comment: There is, like i said i create new code for isolate the big program, see new part in the initial post

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved,
this is the problem:

sql = "SELECT couponsystem.coupon.* FROM couponsystem.company_coupon LEFT JOIN couponsystem.coupon ON "
            + "couponsystem.company_coupon.COUPON_ID = couponsystem.coupon.ID WHERE couponsystem.company_coupon.COMP_ID = ? AND ?";

the second ? is illegal, but the exception is ResultSet closed and not query issue

Answer (score -2):

the problem is you are trying to go back to the previous record in the result set which is not possible.

learn about scrollable resultset and make it insensitive, once you use this you can go back to the previous record by using rs.previous()

ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE

Comment: That would not cause a `ResultSet closed` exception, and the problem doesn't occur in the `previous()` call anyway.